# How to set the max height of a list view

Tags: android, listview

I have 3 vertical parts on the screen:

1. Some texts
2. Listview
3. Some more text fields

I don't understand why when there are more elements in the listview, it takes the whole screen to the bottom without leaving place for the 3rd part and makes this 3rd part unreachable and not visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.transport.ScreenDelivery">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_customer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView_pallets"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_signature"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: are you sure the linear layouts around the textviews are necessary? If you are not planning to use them for something specific later they seem unnecessary (and might cause unexpected behaviour)

Comment: @HendrikMarx I have much more then those two textViews in those layouts, but my idea was to keep it simple for the forum questin.

Comment: @stefan.stt can you post your full xml may be a gist..

Comment: @SahilManchanda https://pastebin.com/eydXy5in

Comment: @stefan.stt check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.transport.ScreenDelivery">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_expectedSum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Очаквана сума"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Очаквана сума" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_expectedSumNum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="-" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_signature"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Подпис"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Подпис" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_signatureField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_returnSum"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="Сума за връщане"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                tools:text="Сума за връщане" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/_returnSumField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_remarks"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Бележка"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Бележка" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_note"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
                    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editText_note"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint=""
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_image"
                    android:layout_width="269dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="Снимка"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:text="Снимка" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_takePhoto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
                    android:onClick="takePhoto"
                    android:text="Снимай"
                    tools:text="Снимай" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_deliveryPhoto"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:contentDescription="Снимка на доставката"
                    android:maxHeight="200dp"
                    android:maxWidth="200dp"
                    android:minHeight="50dp"
                    android:minWidth="50dp"
                    app:srcCompat="?android:attr/alertDialogIcon" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Запази"
                tools:text="Запази" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_customer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Клиент"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="Клиент" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_palletCount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Брой палета"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="Брой палета" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_palletCountNum"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="-"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:text="-" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView_pallets"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_layout" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you can find a solution only using the constraint layout and removing your linear layouts altogether but I don't  know enough about ConstraintLayout to help you there. However you can give weights to the elements inside your Outermost LinearLayout. e.g. assign `android:weightSum="3"` to your outermost LinearLayout and then `android:layout_weight="1"` to the inner elements (in your case the other LinearLayouts)